# Downloading files with progressbar horizontal using parse

Tags: android

I have 37 files to download and I wanted to show my progress bar complete in 100%. how can I set that my last file will equal to 100%.. sorry for my english. thanks in advance..

```
querySound.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
                Log.d("OBJECTS MP3", ""+objects.toString());


                if (objects == null) {

                    Toast.makeText(ParseStarterProjectActivity.this,"Something is Wrong!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                } else {
                    final int adder = 100 / objects.size();
                    for(ParseObject po : objects){              

                        ParseFile sounds = (ParseFile) po.get("remindersSpanish");
                        final String filenames = sounds.getName().substring(37, sounds.getName().length());
                        Log.d("OBJECTS NAME", filenames);
                        sounds.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void done(byte[] data,ParseException e) {
                                Log.d("OBJECTS DATA", ""+data);
                                if (e == null) {
                                    saveMp3(filenames, data);
                                    counter = counter + adder;


                                } else {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }

                                    prgBar.setProgress(counter);
                                    counterPrg.setText(counter+"/"+prgBar.getMax());



                            }
                        });
```